# Ubuntu Cloud image 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) only has one network interface (eth0)

Tags: networking, cloud, ubuntu-14.04, kvm

i'm really new in the cloud world so i need some help because after several day surfing the internet i didn't find anything..

I launch a VM with kvm using this image:
[cloud-images.ubuntu.com/server/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img/ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/server/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img/ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img) .

After i passing the password with cloud-utils file i can login into the new VM but only has one network interface, anyone know other image with two interfaces i can use?? because i need to have 2 interfaces eth0 for my project.

On the internet i found maybe in this path /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rule i can find my local network rules to name your network cards, but in my case i checked the path and i don't have the file "70-persistent-net.rules"

some ideas what can i do? o what image i can use? or maybe other way to solve my problem??

Thanks

Ivan

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general OS tech support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should either be on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/tour) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour).